# Transient error when trying to log in to Microsoft email

Tags: logging

Getting transient error when trying to log into Microsoft email.

Microsoft
Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS90033: A transient error has occurred. Please try again.

Comment: The tag [**logging**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logging) is intended to be used for recording events in a computer program or computer system,

Answer (score 0):

There was a brief Azure Active Directory outage that occurred on September 28, which was when this question was posted. My guess is that your issue was related to that outage, as this outage caused a transient error and prevented people from logging in to services.

If any error like this occurs in the future, please check the Azure status site to check if the service is running. https://status.azure.com/